# iPhone 4S restarting 20x a day since iOS 8.4.1 was installed

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-music

I have an iPhone 4S it is restarting 20x a day since iOS 8.4.1 was installed.  I have the Apple Music service turned on. I am going to turn it off because it keeps causing problems with playing iTunes, but I wonder if anyone else has experienced these restarts, and if so, what configuration options cause it or make it go away.

If it turns out turning off Apple Music solves this issue, I'll post that as an answer. Any other idea?

*Update:* The backup/reset/restore suggested in the answer below also cleared up 20 gb of JUNK/crap in the "Other" category from my iPhone:

[image]

Comment: Impressive that your running 8.4 on a 4s to begin with, how's the performance?

Comment: Slow. Not recommended.  I have retired this handset it's just used for developer-testing on real hardware in XCode now, not my daily carry phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this popped up right after an OS upgrade than I would wipe the phone and restore from backup:

1. Backup phone in iTunes
2. In Settings > General > Reset: erase all content and settings
3. Once that is done restore from backup

My guess is that a file got damaged during the upgrade and restoring it *may* fix it.

Comment: RECOMMENDATION:  CHANGE YOUR ITUNES BACKUP PASSWORD BEFORE DOING THIS!  Otherwise Apple iTunes backup will use some ancient password (it doesn't ask you if you want to encrypt, it just does it) you may have forgotten the last one you input into iTunes in 2010, leading you to LOSE DATA!   A backup done with a saved-long-ago encryption-password is a HORRIBLE design decision that APPLE seems to have instituted ever since iOS 7.